# Connect Hyper-V VM guest to servers over VPN

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vpn, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise computer at home (the Host) that is connecting to the office network using the Windows (built-in) VPN  provider.

I have a VM, also running Windows 10 Enterprise (the Guest), that I'm running under Hyper-V on the Host.

I need to be able to run software on the Guest that accesses servers running on the office network.

This seems like a pretty simple, and common scenario, that should just work out of the box, but when I run the Guest, it has no internet access at all. Not to the the servers over the VPN, not to the wider internet, not to the host.

I'd think there would be simple instructions, somewhere, explaining exactly how to make this work, but what I've found with web searches has been confusing, contradictory, and nothing that I've tried following these contradictory instructions has worked.

Can someone explain to me exactly how to make this work, or better yet, point me to some actual documentation?

Comment: What VPN server are you connecting to, Cisco, SonicWall, Fortinet, etc?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Hyper-V, I've had to go into the network settings of the VM in question and manually configure DNS settings.  I usually use 1.0.0.1 & 1.1.1.1.  I haven't (yet) found a clever way to have DNS automatically assigned correctly in my new Hyper-V VMs, but that might get you up and going.

Leaving the IP address configured via DHCP usually works fine, but that can vary depending on how your network is configured.

Comment: I don't have an ethernet connection at all, within the VM.

Comment: You need to configure an external switch for Hyper-V first then.